# Support of sum of dependent truncated distributions

Tags: distributions, truncated-normal-distribution

In case of independent truncated distributions, we can know the support of their sums from their convolutions. How about the dependent counterparts? In my case, I sum 9 dependent truncated distributions, which the support of each of the distribution is between -1 and 1. So, if they are independent I get -9 and 9 (by simulation). But, since they are dependent I get bigger than -9 and less than 9.

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry if my last statement ('I get bigger than -9 and less than 9.') is not clear. What I meant was $[a,b]$, where $-9 \leq a \leq b \leq 9$. In my case $a$ is 0, and $b$ is 6.1.

Comment: Thank you for setting that straight--I'll delete my comment lest it confuse other readers.  Indeed yes, the support can be smaller than the mathematical limits.  For instance, consider $n$ variables constrained to sum to zero: the support of their sum, by construction, is just $\{0\}$.  The problem is that one cannot say anything in general: the support of a sum of dependent variables has to be computed on a case-by-case basis.